# .htaccess - execute PHP in .html files on FastCGI

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, server, fastcgi

I'm using PHP with FastCGI and I have the following problem. I know the command for .htaccess:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FcgidWrapper /path/to/php-fastcgi.fcgi .html
```

...but I don't know to what path the `FcgidWrapper` should point. To which file or directory should it point, and where is it usually?

Thanks!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidwrapper

Comment: @hjpotter92 I appreciate it that you want to help me, but this does not help me at all, because I don't understand a word. If you could explain this to me, I'd apppreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The path you are asking for is system dependent, so only your sys-admin will be able to answer that question.  You should probably just rename your html files with php in them to use the php extension.  Sending html files without php in them to fcgi is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<Files ~ (\.html)>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .html
    Options +ExecCGI
    allow from all
</Files>
```